# I can't find sawtooth-client-defalut while running sawtooth-default.yaml

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

can any one please suggest what is going wrong with me????????

[Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRGlk.png)

Comment: There is no container call "sawtooth-client-default" in the sawtooth-default.yaml. Could you be more specific? When you run docker-compose, do you see the log output? If so, at that point what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please attach a more complete set of logs from the `docker-compose` command, as text rather than a screenshot, and include the actual command you typed at the command line. Try running `docker-compose -f sawtooth-default.yaml down` first, then repeat your command and see if the issue persists.

Comment: http://root@f39378ea06c2:/# curl http://rest-api:8080/blocks curl: (7) Failed to connect to rest-api port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: i have fixed the previous issue by updating my .yaml file but now when i check the rest-api this error occurs

Comment: generally don't post screenshots and don't over punctuate!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have fixed this problem by editing my Yaml file .
adding this lines

```
client:
image: hyperledger/sawtooth-all:0.8
container_name: sawtooth-client-default
expose:
  - 8080
  - 4004
depends_on:
  - rest-api
entrypoint: "bash -c \"\
    sawtooth keygen && \
    tail -f /dev/null \
    \""
```

so the client container starts and my host is running well now.

Answer (score 3):

Since sawtooth version 1.0.1, the `sawtooth-client-default` container has been renamed as `sawtooth-shell-default`.

Try `docker exec -it sawtooth-shell-default bash`

If you're using 0.8 or any version of sawtooth earlier than 1.0.1, I'd suggest to upgrade to 1.0.1 or higher.

The latest 1.0.1 or higher documentation is [here](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/contents.html)